# Drop Down Menu Missing on Import All Product Page

Tags: import, menu

Hello: I did an upload the other day and just out of nowhere, my drop down menu is missing  on the "run profile" page! I can upload the file, then put that file name under "File Information" but it's just one extra step I don't need. Any ideas on how to get this back? Thanks![image: Snippet of what the page looks like.]

Comment: Please accept the answer that helped you to mark this question as "answered". Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do you happen to have selected "Local/Remote server" in the Profile Wizard? If so, change it back to Interactive; This will help you get your dropdown back :)

Comment: @GayleW please select my answer so this question gets closed :-)